# PHP fopen() and php://memory not working as expected (data-loss)

Tags: php, curl, fopen, php-stream-wrappers

I am currently trying to integrate a Class that uses `fopen()` with a `php://memory` stream to capture Curl headers.  There are invariably better ways to capture the Curl headers, but I am not with enough time to write my own class at this moment.

The issue is that no header information is captured.  The code is as follows:

```
    $response_headers_fh = fopen('php://memory', 'wb+');

    $ch->setOpt(CURLOPT_WRITEHEADER, $response_headers_fh);

    $ch->raw_response = curl_exec($ch->curl);

    rewind($response_headers_fh);
    $ch->raw_response_headers = stream_get_contents($response_headers_fh);
    fclose($response_headers_fh);
```

At this point, after the Curl request, the `$ch->raw_response_headers` property is empty.  However, if I specify a file-path:

```
    $response_headers_fh = fopen('/tmp/random_string', 'wb+');

    $ch->setOpt(CURLOPT_WRITEHEADER, $response_headers_fh);
```

The `$ch->raw_response_headers` property is set properly...

Our PHP version is:

```
$ php -v
PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Sep 10 2014 07:51:23)
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by Derick Rethans
```

Kind of stumped...

Comment: I guess you need to open it as `rwb`, not `wb+`.

Comment: I tried that, it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is plausible that curl isn't able to write to the `php://memory` stream. There is an old [bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=43468) that seems unresolved until now. But you can use the [`CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html)-option to capture the header instead:

```
function MyHeaderFunction($ch, $header)
{
    echo 'Header = ' . $header;
    return strlen($header);
}

$ch->setopt(CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, 'MyHeaderFunction');

curl_exec($ch->curl);
```